# Disable ribbon button if one folder is selected

Tags: 2010, javascript, ribbon

This script works but only for one selected item

```
 EnabledScript="javascript:
              var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
              (items.length == 1 &amp;&amp; items[0].fsObjType == 0);"/>
```

I need that the user can select many files or folder.  If in the selection there is at least one folder, button should be disabled, if all items are just files, button should be enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use something like this (not tested):

```
for (int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
{
   if (items[i].fsObjType == 1)
      return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: items[0] would test always the first element of the list, isnt it?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake :) I've updated.

Comment: how can I escape the < character?

Comment: Error 10 Character '<', hexadecimal value 0x3c is illegal in XML attribute values.

Comment: cant find how to escape that :(

Comment: I escaped it, but now I have a bigger problem. lol. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/expected-on-javascript