# Expected ; on javascript

Tags: javascript, ribbon

I got the following code in my elements.xml, but I cant find the error.

My ribbon is broken, the error says, expected;.

But I see no error, yet, maybe fresh eyes can see it.
See the EnabledScript section:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use int in javascript: <del>javascript:
              for (int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
              {
                  if (items[i].fsObjType == 1)
                     return false;
              }
              return true;</del>

with:

```
javascript:
for (var i =0; i &lt; items.length; i++)
{
        if (items[i].fsObjType == 1)
             return false;
}
return true;
```

UPDATE After the update of the question: You define your function in EnabledScript but you never invoke this. According to [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx) you have to invoke it:

```
EnabledScript="javascript:function SomeAppropriateNamForFunction()
{
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    for (var i =0; i &lt; items.length; i++)
    {
            if (items[i].fsObjType == 1)
                 return false;
    }
    return true;
}
SomeAppropriateNamForFunction();"
```

Comment: now it says, return statement out of function?

Comment: I updated the question with the current code in the enabled script, but it doesnt down what is needed to do.

Comment: According to [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx), you have to invoke your function as well. See my updated answer.

Comment: lol indeed, thanks for your answer, it works perfect now.

Comment: +1 for finding the missing function. :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
 EnabledScript="javascript:
              for (int i =0; i &lt; items.length; i++)
              {
                  if (items[i].fsObjType == 1)
                     return false;
              }
              return true;"/>
```

**items** is unassigned variable.

Comment: please see my update, however its not working, the button is always disabled no matter what I select, I dont have javascript errors anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  EnabledScript="javascript: function isNonFolderSelected() {
                  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
                  var result = true;
                  for (var i = 0; i &lt; selectedItems.length; i++) {
                      // it is a list item, not a folder
                      if (selectedItems[i].fsObjType == '1') {
                          result = false;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  return result;
              }
              isNonFolderSelected();"
```